# flutter angle value of Transform.rotate dont change and dont update state

Tags: flutter, provider, state-management

this is my code

```
class TitleGreen extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
print('title green buile');
return  Positioned(
    key:  UniqueKey(),
    top: 0.0,
    child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Provider.of<MoveDetailsDesVisibility>(context)
              .setViisibility(1, context);
        },
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          key:  UniqueKey(),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 0),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: Provider.of<MoveDetailsDesVisibility>(context)
                  .des2visibility
                  ? (1 / 4) * height + 225
                  : (1 / 4) * height + 115),

          height: Provider.of<MoveDetailsDesVisibility>(context)
              .des2visibility
              ? (1 / 4) * height + 260
              : (1 / 4) * height + 150,
          //150
          width: (3 / 4) * width - 11.5,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xFF24DC25),
              borderRadius:
              BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30))),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 5,
                  ),

                  Transform.rotate(
                      key:  UniqueKey(),
                      angle: Provider.of<MoveDetailsDesVisibility>(context)
                          .des2visibility?-80:0,
                      child:
                      Image.asset(
                        'assets/icons/faNote.png',
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        width: 20,
                        height: 20,
                      )),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 9,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'توضیحات مربی',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  )
                ],
              ),

            ],
          ),
        )));
   }
}
```

in this code when i update provider and change value of provider whole of this widget class called and build method was called but this codidation that check if value of "des2visibility" is false or true dont call and image widget dont transform while whole of widget built where is incorrect i test it with consumer and take whole widget key value but dont work

Comment: can you add your provider class ?

Comment: where and how? please explaine

Comment: i mean add MoveDetailsDesVisibility class here.

Comment: what do you mean "when i update provider "? you mean when you call "setViisibility" ?

also, are you sure you didn't forget to call notifyListeners()?

Comment: pskink what talk about i dont want animation .

Comment: @loVe yes i sure

Comment: can you share the code where you used consumer? as well as the provider class? Bcz according to your info everything looks fine!

Comment: @loVe i ll send idlt next day bcz now dont acces to code this is my tel id M_R_Sh_1999

Answer (score 0):

It is an stateless widget you should use stateful widget Titlegreen

Comment: ssdn please note i use provider stateManagment

Comment: add this constructor ...  const TitleGreen ({Key key}) : super(key: key); ...into TitleGreen  class

Comment: your answers dont work and i am couldnot solve this problem with provider but i solve it with setState method thank you all